# I'm having problems recording sound effects at low volumes

Tags: field, recording, effects

I have been recording sounds like a rubber glove on glass and its going in at -22db. If i turn it up more I get a lot of fuzzy noise. I recorded low then opened it in pro tools. I turned up the volume to make sure it was clean, then I hear that fuzzy noise in everything I have recorded! So the only way I can get it out is with a gate. So my question is do you use a gate in "post recording" or do you record without any noise? I can't seem to get the fuzzy noise out of my recordings during recording. I have my mic trim at 8 out of ten and level set to 5 out of ten. Also do you use a limiter to get a quite sound louder once the sound is all cleaned up?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Shaun, what you're hearing is likely a combination of microphone self-noise and the self-noise of your preamp, as well...a consequence of either not being close enough to the sound, insufficiently sensitive mics, or low-cost preamps. What mic and recorder are you using, and how close are you to the sound source? Usually the answer to such problems are:

1. Get closer to the source
2. Get a quieter preamp
3. Get a quieter mic

...and that's in order of ease and cost, generally. You might be hearing something else, though: What you describe could be anything from traffic noise to RF interference, but if you hear it in all your quiet recordings, the top advice probably still stands.

Details about quiet mics can be found in [this thread](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/1891/who-makes-the-quietest-microphone).

Comment: @NoiseJockey I was using a Fostex Fr2-LE with a Samson c02 small cap condenser at about 4 inches from the source. I think it is pre amp noise. I will try recording the same thing with a different recorder and different mic to see if there is a difference. Thanks. 

Comment: @NoiseJockey I just looked at the specs for the mic I used and found out it has 22dba of noise. It is meant to be used for recording overheads and to be close to a fairly loud source. 

Comment: Also gotta ask the dumb question: Are you listening to the recording on the FR2-LE or on your PC? The FR2-LE's headphone preamp is way noisier than the mic preamps, and can lead you to think the noise floor is way higher than it really is. FWIW!

Comment: Final thought: The best, cheap mic I've found for quiet sources is the Røde NT1a. There are cheaper, and there are better, but there isn't better for less dough. Large condensers are often overlooked, but they rock for indoor material, esp. close-miked stuff!

Comment: I have a Rode NTG2 on its way, should get here within the next couple weeks. I have a cheaper mxl large cap I can try out. Thanks for the advice. I was listening on my mac so its not the noisy headphone amp i'm hearing. thanks 

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you are just starting out, you must relativize. Now, I'm not going to be saying that you should not do whatever is worth to get the best sound, I'm going to be saying you have to know your limits.

If you're not in the position of getting any other/new gear and you're stuck with what you have, you will be learning the limits of your equipment as you're using it. It is probably what you are facing just now. I am in the same situation, except that I'm getting to try and buy new equipment.

Yes, the amount of processing (such as gating/BNR) you and me and our fellow on-a-budget beginners have to apply to our sounds does seem to be a lot. At some point you just can't get as close as you'd like to that other pro recording that you know of. As much as you try, your sound does not feel as raw anymore.

I recently was reading The Sounds of Star Wars and it felt great to read that even in such an epic movie (well I'm not a big fan but many people seem to be), the sound effects were not always perfect. Apparently on some sound effect you'd be able to hear somebody closing the fridge door in the above room...

In the end, it's not the sound of your life that you're recording just now. At some point, trying to look for the perfect sounding thing takes you away from achieving your global vision...

To answer your question, I reckon first compress, then expand... your expanding will be more precise and efficient if you're working on compressed dynamics. Again, be aware you might not get the perfect sound, but it's ok for now ;)

Comment: @Justin Huss thanks for this. It helps to know that not everything will be perfect with any type of gear. Now I can be at ease, instead of getting frustrated that I get fuzz in my recordings. I do buy new gear about every 6 months so a big gap but it gives me time to learn the gear's limits as you said. 

Answer (score 0):

Everything I would have suggested I have mentioned.  You should get better results with the NTG2...just make sure the room is super quiet...the NTG2 picks up too much background noise for my liking.

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't always possible, another low cost solution is to try performing your sound as loud as possible to help the signal to noise ratio. This can often sound "wrong" as you're performing the sound, but I'm often pleasantly surprised when I play back. If I need to re-perform a sound with more level for s/n reasons, I'll often ditch the headphones as I find I record quieter with them on.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a gate, multiband compression, and iZotope RX Spectral denoise/repair on sounds that I have recorded.  Once, I recorded water drops and when i normalized them, or raised the gain there was a lot of mic-self noise, some room tone, and pre-amp noise.  iZotope RX did pretty well with removing the noise.

Answer (score 0):

if you're recording it at a lower volume and bringing the volume up later
than you're also bringing up the volume of the white noise.

Best off recording at the volume you want it to be relative to how much you're going to increase it in the loudness part of the master..

i mean if your master is going to be 10 db higher than your mixdown
then you still want the single audio track to be 10 db lower than that but you don't want to have to increase it by any db in the mixdown before the master because then you're increasing the white noise even more than you have to

I'm having trouble with the xpand plugin in pro tools.
seems like no matter what I do.. anything from that plugin at a lower volume is going to sound staticy
but If I'm using east west... no problems at all
damnit

Comment: hi state, this is a rather old question that is already answered. furthermore, your answer is not adding a lot to the discussion, besides your own statement about xpand plugins. perhaps you've answered the wrong question, just curious.

Comment: I thought the bit about making sure you're recording at the appropriate volume would be helpful. After all, nipping the problem in the butt at the source is always the best solution. and the bit about the xpand plugin might make someone realize that it's the specific plugins they're using that could be causing the problem in certain cases. factory plugins can have those problems ;)